# Передача данных от клиента на сервер в формате JSON с помощью jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте! Вот, казалось бы простой пример. Пользователь вводит текст, нажимает на кнопку, перезагрузки не происходит (технология AJAX), данные попадают на сервер и обрабатываются (преобразуем в верхний регистр). Если запрос выполнен удачно, отобразится слово Yes и данные с сервера, если нет, то слово Error. Все просто, да оказалось не все. Посмотрите код, что не так?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Страница</title>
 <!-- подключаем библиотеку онлайн через Google CDN -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="a.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="a" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
 </form>
 <p></p>
 <br />
 <br />
 <label></label>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('button').click(function() {
   //преобразуем данные формы в строку, но нам же нужен формат JSON
   //var data = $('form').serialize();

   //создаем объект данных
   var obj {
    a: $('[name=a]').val()
   }
   //превращаем объект в строку формата JSON
   var strInForm = JSON.stringify(obj);

   $.ajax({
   url: "a.php",
   cache: false,
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: strInForm,
   success: function (str) {
    $('p').text('Yes!');
    //превращаем строку формата JSON в массив
    var ara = JSON.parse(str);
    //обращаемся к массиву по индексу
    $('label').text(ara[0]);
   },
   error: function() {
    $('p').text('Error!');
   }
  });
  });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**a.php**

```
<?php
 //строковые данные должны быть в кодировке UTF-8
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 //обычный способ, строка пришла на сервер
 //$str = $_POST['a'];

 //но теоретически, должна ведь приходить строка, которую
 //мы превратили из объекта в строку формата JSON
 //и она должна соотвествовать строке, указанной в data: strInForm
 $str = $_POST['strInForm'];

 //теперь превращаем эту строку в массив, так как она может
 //иметь несколько значений
 $ara1 = json_decode($str);

 //что-то делаем на сервере, преобразуем строку в верхний регистр
 $str = strtoupper($ara1[0]);

 //теперь будем отправлять строку обратно
 //помещаем строку в массив
 $ara2 = array($str);

 //кодируем массив в строку формата JSON
 $str = json_encode($ara2);

 //возрващаем строку в формате JSON
 echo = $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде ошибка на ошибке и ошибкой погоняет.

php - последняя строка должна быть не `echo = $str;` а `echo $str;` и слишком много странных операций нахождение в коде которых для меня остается загадкой.

html - у `button` тип не `submit` а `button`, потому что иначе она в любом случае отправляет данные с перезагрузкой страницы. Если нужно чтобы была именно `button` то нужно убрать действие по умолчанию (`event.preventDefault()`).

javascript - `JSON.parse` не нужен, если у вас `dataType === json`. Ответ и так придет в `JSON`. Отправляете вы объект со свойством `a` а считываете в PHP `strInForm` (`//$str = $_POST['a'];` - правильный вариант).

В общем, у вас слишком много ошибок в коде, которые мешают разобраться где именно косяк. Хотя возможно как только вы все исправите все заработает ;)

Comment: Мешает то что это сайт с вопросами, а не аля "вот вам кривой код, но он почемуто не работает, и так как мне лень сделайте все за меня". И все эти ошибки и были выявлены когда я проверял этот код у себя. Вы сказали что код не работает - я сказал почему.

Comment: Уважаемый  DOC_tr, я так понимаю, код у Вас не заработал...Ошибки Вы выявили, но код у Вас так и не заработал...

Answer (score 1):

Исправил несколько моментов:

1. Вставил знак `=`

   ```
   //создаем объект данных
   var obj **=** {
       a: $('[name=a]').val()
   };
   ```
2. Добавил в конец обработчика события `click` кнопки `return false;` чтобы кнопка не срабатывала на отправку формы.
3. Исправил `echo = $str;` на `echo $str;`.

**UPD**

Обновил код, теперь работает передача данных.

Исправления:

4. Убрал `var strInForm = JSON.stringify(obj);`. Передаю просто объект `obj` в качестве значения свойства `data` при вызове `$.ajax()`.
5. Убрал `json_decode($str);` в PHP — данные приходят в обычном виде. Вам нужно только кодировать данные в JSON при возврате результата работы PHP-скрипта.
6. Исправил `type: "POST"` на `method: "POST"`.
7. Возвращаю из PHP не нумерованный массив с одним элементом `[$str]`, а ассоциативный массив `['result' => $str]`.
8. В обработчике `success` переименовал параметр `str` в `data`, убрал `var ara = JSON.parse(str);` — данные приходят в виде JS-объекта (вам не нужно обрабатывать JSON никак).
   Получаю результат по индексу `result` из переменной `data`: `data['result']`.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Страница</title>
 <!-- подключаем библиотеку онлайн через Google CDN -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="a.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="a" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
 </form>
 <p></p>
 <br />
 <br />
 <label></label>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('button').click(function() {
   //создаем объект данных
   var obj = {
    a: $('[name=a]').val()
   };
   //превращаем объект в строку формата JSON
   //var strInForm = JSON.stringify(obj);

   $.ajax({
   url: "a.php",
   cache: false,
   method: "POST",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: obj,
   success: function (data) {
    $('p').text('Yes!');
    //превращаем строку формата JSON в массив
    //var ara = JSON.parse(str);
    //обращаемся к массиву по индексу
    $('label').text(data['result']);
   },
   error: function(e) {
    $('p').text('Error!');
   }
  });
  return false;
  });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
 <?php
 //строковые данные должны быть в кодировке UTF-8
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 //обычный способ, строка пришла на сервер
 //$str = $_POST['a'];

 //но теоретически, должна ведь приходить строка, которую
 //мы превратили из объекта в строку формата JSON
 //и она должна соотвествовать строке, указанной в data: a
 $str = $_POST['a'];

 //теперь превращаем эту строку в массив, так как она может
 //иметь несколько значений
 //$ara1 = json_decode($str);

 //что-то делаем на сервере, преобразуем строку в верхний регистр
 //$str = strtoupper($ara1[0]);
 $str = strtoupper($str);

 //теперь будем отправлять строку обратно
 //помещаем строку в массив
 $ara2 = array('result' => $str);

 //кодируем массив в строку формата JSON
 $str = json_encode($ara2);

 //возрващаем строку в формате JSON
 echo $str;
```

Comment: Здравствуйте Vladimir Serykh! Ваш ответ является эталоном! Вот именно в таком формате должны быть ответы. Отдельно вынесены ошибки. Показан полный код, который можно вставить и протестировать! Но, код "немножко" не работает. Данные на сервер уходят и...не приходят.  Я исправлю код и допишу его в вопросе.

Comment: Я обновил вчера код. Если он работает и вам помог, отметьте мой ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Тяжелое предисловие...Как я понимал предназначение JSON. Основная задача JSON является передача данных между клиентом и сервером и обратно.

Теоретически, данные на клиенте, мы должны превратить в JSON объект, а затем с помощью `JSON.stringify()` превратить в строку для отправки на сервер.

На сервере мы должны эту строку превратить в массив с помощью json_decode(), что бы работать с этими данными. Мы ведь и так с ними работаем, как с элементами массива `$_POST`, в этом примере `$_POST['a']`, а теоретически должно прийти за один раз `$_POST['strInForm']`, мы ведь эту строку `data: strInForm` указывали в функции `$.ajax()`. То есть, в одной ячейке массива `$_POST` приходит строка в формате JSON, которую мы должны превратить в массив. Это я так думал...

Далее, мы что-то сделали с этими данными массива и теперь опять должны превратить в строку с помощью `json_encode()` и отправляем на клиент.

На клиенте, эту строку нужно превратить в массив с помощью `JSON.parse()`. Это я то же так думал...

**В общем, заблуждался, как мог.**

1) исравляем `type="submit"` на  `type="button"`

2) создание объекта

```
var obj = {
 a: $('[name=a]').val()
};
```

и превращение объекта в строку формата JSON

```
var strInForm = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

"почему-то" не работает, прийдется использовать обычный вариант

```
var strInForm = $('form').serialize();
```

3)превращение строки формата JSON, пршедшей с сервера, в массив то же "почему-то" не работает

```
var ara = JSON.parse(str);
```

поэтому, обращаемся к этой строке, как к уже готовому массиву

```
$('label').text(str[0]);
```

4)файл a.php переделал полностью.

5)Возникла другая ошибка, если пользователь введет слово на русском языке, то будут выведена абра-кодабра. Возможно, проблему перекодировки можно решить с помощью `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` в PHP5.4, но у меня версия меньше.

```
$str = json_encode($ara, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Страница</title>
 <!-- подключаем библиотеку онлайн через Google CDN -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="a.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="a" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <!--исравляем type="submit" на  type="button"-->
  <button type="button">OK</button>
 </form>
 <p></p>
 <br />
 <label></label>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('button').click(function() {

   var strInForm = $('form').serialize();

   $.ajax({
   url: "a.php",
   cache: false,
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: strInForm,
   success: function (str) {
    $('p').text('Yes!');
    //обращаемся к массиву по индексу
    $('label').text(str[0]);
   },
   error: function() {
    $('p').text('Error!');
   }
  });
  });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**a.php**

```
<?php
 //строковые данные должны быть в кодировке UTF-8
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 //строка пришла на сервер
 $str = $_POST['a'];

 //что-то делаем на сервере, преобразуем строку в верхний регистр
 $str = strtoupper($str);

 //отправляем обратно, помещаем строку в массив
 $ara = array($str);

 //кодируем массив в строку формата JSON
 $str = json_encode($ara);

 //возрващаем строку в формате JSON
 echo $str;
```